# Finitely generated projective modules over polynomial rings with integral coefficients

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

There is famous [Quillen-Suslin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quillen-Suslin_theorem) which states that every finitely generated projective module over a ring of polynomials $k[x_1,...,x_n]$, where $k$ is a field, is free.

I have never carefully read a proof of this theorem, which is for example in the **Lang's Algebra**. `Probably it is based on Quillen's original ideas.`- this is not true as it was pointed out in the answer below.

**Questions:** Is every finitely generated projective modules over $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_n]$ free?

If yes, then is the proof modification of the one given in **Lang's Algebra**?

And if yes, then how about polynomial rings over other Dedekind domains or number rings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok Slup, here goes.

Let $R$ be any commutative ring and let $A$ be a polynomial ring over $R$. Let $P$ be any projective module over $R$. Then Quillen (and Suslin a bit later in this generality) proved that if for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $R$, $P_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is of the form $Q\otimes_{R_{\mathfrak{m}}} A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ for some projective $R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ module $Q$, then there exists a projective module $Q$ over $R$ such that $P=Q\otimes_R A$. Using this, they deduced that this always happens when $R$ is a Dedekind domain. The last part is done by the following observation. If for such a $P$, $P_f$ is free for a polynomial which is monic in one of the variables, then $P$ is free. As you can see, since any non-zero polynomial after a change of variables can be made into a monic polynomial in one of the variables if $R$ is a field, one immediately deduces Serre conjecture from this.

Many years later, Lindel generalized this for $R$ any regular ring containing a field.

Comment: What do you mean by 'this' in your sentence 'Lindel  generalized this for $R$ any regular ring containing a field'?

Comment: Lindel proved that any projective module over $A$ (notation as above) comes from $R$ by tensoring as above.

Comment: Serre's conjecture is false for Dedekind domains

Comment: I do not know what you mean. The theorem that is proved is that projective modules come from the base in these cases (for example Dedekind domains). Of course they are not free, since there are non-free projective modules over Dedekind domains, unless it is a pid.

Comment: I meant that if $A$ is a dedekind domain, then in general not every finite type projective $A[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$-module is free. (This was the OP's initial question.) I think the OP (and me too) would like to know some more rings $A$ (not pids, is being a pid necessary?) such that every finite type projective $A[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$-module is free. Do you know of a survey paper that discusses such $A$?. I think it is true for $A$ Bezout. Aren't you actually a reasearch mathematician in CA? I think I heard your name somewhere

Comment: I was just explaining some of the most general theorems known in this direction, while also giving an answer to the best of my knowledge to the question posed. I know too little about non-Noetherian rings.

Comment: I have explained below my argument resolving the case for Dedekind domains. Do you think that it is of some value, or was it obvious from the start that it doesn't hold for non-pid's? I couldn't find it in the literature. It seems like it is one of these things that no one bother to write down.

Comment: For a non pid Dedekind domain $R$, a projective non-free module over $R$ gives a non-free projective module over $A$, by tensoring (with notation as in my answer above)

Comment: @Mohan I thought about this, but kind of wanted to preserve the connection with K theory as wished by the OP. do you know whether this point of view is useful? At the moment it seems like  a complicated proof for something simple

Answer (score 2):

Let us say that a ring $A$ satisfies condition $(S)$ if every finite type projective $A$-module is free. Clearly a necessary condition for $(S)$ to hold is $K_0(A)=\mathbf{Z}$.

*Example.* (i) If $A$ is local Noetherian then $(S)$ holds.
(ii) If $A$ is a Dedekind domain then $K_0(A)=\mathbf{Z}\oplus\mathrm{Pic}(A)$, and thus a necessary condition for $(S)$ is $\mathrm{Pic}(A)=0$, which is the case iff $A$ is a pid.

**Theorem.**(Grothendieck) If $A$ is a regular ring then we have a canonical isomorphism $K_0(A)\rightarrow K_0(A[(T_i)_{i\in I}])$.

Thus a necessary condition for $(S)$ to hold for $A[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$ is $K_0(A)=\mathbf{Z}$.

*Corollary.* Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain. Then $(S)$ holds for $A[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$ if and only if $\mathrm{Pic}(A)=0$, i.e. iff $A$ is a pid.

(This follows from what we said previously and Quillen's theorem stating that if $A$ is a pid, then $A[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$ satisfies $(S)$.)

(*Remark.* Quillen's original proof is different from the one given in Lang!)

Comment: Thank you for answer and pointing out to that the original proof is different. Is there any research in the direction of number rings?

Comment: It is true in greater generality. To specilaize to your case, if $P$ is a projective module over a polynomial ring $A$ over a ring of integers $R$ (the set of all algebraic integers in a number field), and more generally for any Dedekind domain, then there exists a projective module $Q$ over $R$ such that $P=Q\otimes_R A$. In particular, $P=F\oplus L$ where $F$ is free and $L$ is a projective module of rank one. Further, $L$ comes from $R$ and thus if $R$ is a pid, then $L$ too is free.

Comment: It has something to do with $K$-theory? Please turn your comment into answer, other two answers are very valuable, but your is the most complete one.

Comment: Thanks for adding this reformulation in terms of $K$-theory. I have already up-voted your answer, so there is now way I can award you for that except for expressing my gratitude.

Answer (score 2):

It should be true for any PID. See the book by Lam, Serre's Conjecture

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the reference.